# UIButton title label delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am having a issue with setting the title label for a button. Basically I have 2 screen and both of them have this button, but both have different "number" written on them. What's happening is that there is a very noticeable delay of 1-2 seconds before the button title accurately reflects the screen I'm on. I tried to put `[self.button reloadInputViews];` but it still does not reload it and I still get the delay.

```
[self.button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [stringValue integerValue]]
             forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Does someone know how I can force the button to refresh it's title label? Thanks for the help!

EDIT: More code for context

```
        self.guestsField = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.guestsField.frame = CGRectMake(self.guestsLabel.frame.origin.x + self.guestsLabel.frame.size.width, 100, 40, 30);
    self.guestsField.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
    [self.guestsField addTarget:self action:@selector(pressGuestsField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self.view addSubview:self.guestsField];'
```

myFunction{
NSDictionary* dict = [notification userInfo];

```
    if ([dict count] > 0)
    {
        [self.guestsField setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [GetOrder.NumberOfGuests integerValue]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

}

Fixed it: was running myFunction on a different thread. Just did the setTitle in the main thread `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{`

Comment: Where are you calling this code, and what's happening before and after it? The UI thread will automatically update the title, but if it's busy doing something else, then you'll have to wait.

Comment: I agree with @MarcusAdams... something is chewing up your main thread which is interfering with the UI.

Comment: I'm calling this code inside a function that runs as soon as you switch from one screen to the other.

Comment: You can use the Time Profiler instrument to figure out what's blocking the thread.

Comment: I'm getting some data from a server. But I don't think it should affect it because I'm calling the title label change AFTER I get the information. And it does it ONLY after I get a response.

Comment: I'll try the time profiler right now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are waiting to set the label until after you retrieve data from  the server, it seems that is the reason for your delay. Comment out your networking code and see if your label gets updated instantly.

Comment: Still delay. But one thing I noticed is that when I switch from screen 1 to screen 2, and before it has changed the title to "2", If i click on the button, it changes it to 2 almost instantly. :S

Comment: Post some code please. Can't really help with out seeing what you are doing.